# Android unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

I want to create unit tests for the main part of my application which is APIcalls.java class. Is it possible in android to test these kind of requests? Because every time I call my API get method, I get an error and get nothing from the server. Here is the get method:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

try {

httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
Httpget httpget = new HttpGet(url);

HttpEntity entity = null;
try {
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
  entity = response.getEntity();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.d("Exception", e);
}


if (entity != null) {
  InputStream is = null;
  is = entity.getContent();

try {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   sb.append(line + "\n");
 }
  reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {

       throw e;

   } catch (RuntimeException e) {

       httpget.abort();
        throw e;

   } finally {

     is.close();

   }
   httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.d("Exception", e);
}

String result = sb.toString().trim();

return result;
```

Is it somehow possible to test what kind of data I am receiving from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit test isn't going to have (and really shouldn't need) network access. You should simulate the parts that you can simply assume work using [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and a mocking framework like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/). Use the mocking framework to ensure you test responses for both successes and failures. Try to cover as many types of cases as you might expect in a production environment.

Specifically, in this case you may want to inject an AbstractHttpClient. Then you can mock the execute() method to return exactly the response you need per test, but provide the DefaultHttpClient in production.